# Как перерисовать область в Canvas?

Tags: gwt, java

Необходимо перерисовать область в `Canvas`, не стирая всего изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с Canvas через GWT можно воспользоваться библиотеками: [GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas), [gwt-canvas](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы перерисовать прямоугольную область на Canvas есть метод
repaint(int x, int y, int width, int height).
Но вообще, работая с Java2D, я пришёл к личному для себя выводу, что если нужно рисовать несколько независимых объектов на одном канвасе, намного удобнее иметь несколько объектов BufferedImage для рисования (может кому-то удобнее по-другому) и выводить в canvas их поочереди.

Comment: это недоступно в гвт